# 2 SQL Commands Insert and update to different tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ms-access

have 2 sql commands with commands for different tables.
Here is my code.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string txtbx9 = textBox9.Text.ToString();
        string cmbbx2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string name = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        string surname = textBox2.Text.ToString();
        string company = textBox3.Text.ToString();
        string txtbx8 = textBox8.Text.ToString();
        string sts = "In House";

            try
            {
                connection.Open();


                MessageBox.Show("Payment approved.");
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "The hotel received " + txtbx9 + " from this guest";
                 string rtb = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO billing(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_totalrate, g_paid, g_typepaid, info, u_add, u_tadd, g_ad, g_dd, g_amountofdays) VALUES('" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + company + "','" + txtbx8 + "', '" + txtbx9 + "', '" + cmbbx2 + "', '" + rtb + "', '" + label12.Text.ToString() + "', '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value +"','"+textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox5.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox6.Text.ToString()+"')"; ;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_paidstatus='Paid '"+txtbx9+"'' where g_name ='"+name+"' and g_status = '"+sts"'";

                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

How can i do this 2 commands together?
The program does the first sql command, but not the second one

Comment: You could remove the second `command.Connection = connection; connection.Open();`, just change the command and execute again, and remember to close the connection afterwards.

Comment: Is this for MySql, for Sql Server or for MS-Access? With MySql/Sql Server you could make one single command with two sql statements. This is not possible with access. Your problem is the second connection open when the connection is already open

Comment: @stuartd There is one right after the `try {` and another one before the second `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: @stuartd  thanks! Everything worked

Comment: @KeyurPATEL everything worked! thanks a lot!!! you were correct!

Comment: @A.Aliyev works? Try to insert a name containing a single quote IE g_surname = O'Neill

Comment: @KeyurPATEL thanks, I missed that

Comment: You should consider getting into parametrized queries because 2 reasons: a) Easier to write/support and b) They are a lot safer than concatenating strings with user provided data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute both commends in on command:

```
try
{
      connection.Open();   

      MessageBox.Show("Payment approved.");
      richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "The hotel received " + txtbx9 + " from this guest";
      string rtb = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO billing(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_totalrate, g_paid, g_typepaid, info, u_add, u_tadd, g_ad, g_dd, g_amountofdays) VALUES('" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + company + "','" + txtbx8 + "', '" + txtbx9 + "', '" + cmbbx2 + "', '" + rtb + "', '" + label12.Text.ToString() + "', '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value +"','"+textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox5.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox6.Text.ToString()+"')";
      command.CommandText += "\nUPDATE guestreg SET g_paidstatus='Paid '"+txtbx9+"'' where g_name ='"+name+"' and g_status = '"+sts"'";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Or just execute them one after the other:

```
try
{
      connection.Open();   

      MessageBox.Show("Payment approved.");
      richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "The hotel received " + txtbx9 + " from this guest";
      string rtb = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO billing(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_totalrate, g_paid, g_typepaid, info, u_add, u_tadd, g_ad, g_dd, g_amountofdays) VALUES('" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + company + "','" + txtbx8 + "', '" + txtbx9 + "', '" + cmbbx2 + "', '" + rtb + "', '" + label12.Text.ToString() + "', '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value +"','"+textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox5.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox6.Text.ToString()+"')";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_paidstatus='Paid '"+txtbx9+"'' where g_name ='"+name+"' and g_status = '"+sts"'";
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**EDIT**:

As Steve mentioned (and he is absolutely right), parameters should be passed as `SqlParameters`. The benefits are a better safety against SQL injection and you can be sure, that unexpected inputs like 'O'Neil' don't break your code (parameter names could be better):

```
try
{
      connection.Open();   

      MessageBox.Show("Payment approved.");
      richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "The hotel received " + txtbx9 + " from this guest";
      string rtb = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
      command.Connection = connection;
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO billing(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_totalrate, g_paid, g_typepaid, info, u_add, u_tadd, g_ad, g_dd, g_amountofdays) VALUES(@name,@surname,@company,@txtbx8,@txtbx9,@cmbbx2,@rtb,@label12Text,@dateTimePicker1Value,@textBox4Text,@textBox5Text,@textBox6Text')";
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",name));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@surname",surname));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company",company));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txtbx8",txtbx8));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txtbx9",txtbx9));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmbbx2",cmbbx2));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rtb",rtb));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@label12Text",label12.Text.ToString()));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateTimePicker1Value",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textBox4Text",textBox4.Text.ToString()));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textBox5Text",textBox5.Text.ToString()));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@textBox6Text",textBox6.Text.ToString()));
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_paidstatus=@paidStatus where g_name =@name and g_status = @status";
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paidStatus","Paid " + txtbx9));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",name));
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status",sts));
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This will not work with MS-Access (and you forgot the semicolon between the two command texts)

Comment: I didn't know this was for Access. On SQL Server there is no need for a semicolon between commands

Comment: The OP tagged 3 databases. Only him/her knows

Comment: Ok, but my second suggestion (after Edit) should work then

Comment: Sure it will work until a user has a surname like 'O'Neill'

Comment: The question was not about optimizing unsafe SQL but why the second statement isn't executed. I'm not on a missionary quest to cure the evil of SQL string concatenation.

Comment: If you don't care to give complete answers and recommend the best practices then you have little interest in making your answer a good reference for future readers and thus you should expect someone that criticize your work

Comment: @RomanoZumbé is not about being an evil practice or not, they are also less troublesome and more readable, those and the safety are inmho the reasons worth it should be recommended as best practice.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that but for me the easiest way is to close and re do it like this:

```
SqlCommand importCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from * ", connection);
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = importCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int index = 0;
        while (sqlDR.Read()) { //something }
        sqlDR.Close();

        index = 0;
        importCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from * ", connection);
        sqlDR = importCommand.ExecuteReader();
        sqlDR.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. You have to create command two time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string txtbx9 = textBox9.Text.ToString();
string cmbbx2 = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
string name = textBox1.Text.ToString();
string surname = textBox2.Text.ToString();
string company = textBox3.Text.ToString();
string txtbx8 = textBox8.Text.ToString();
string sts = "In House";

    try
    {
        connection.Open();


        MessageBox.Show("Payment approved.");
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "The hotel received " + txtbx9 + " from this guest";
            string rtb = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO billing(g_name,g_surname,g_company,g_totalrate, g_paid, g_typepaid, info, u_add, u_tadd, g_ad, g_dd, g_amountofdays) VALUES('" + name + "','" + surname + "','" + company + "','" + txtbx8 + "', '" + txtbx9 + "', '" + cmbbx2 + "', '" + rtb + "', '" + label12.Text.ToString() + "', '" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value +"','"+textBox4.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox5.Text.ToString()+"','"+textBox6.Text.ToString()+"')"; ;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE guestreg SET g_paidstatus='Paid '"+txtbx9+"'' where g_name ='"+name+"' and g_status = '"+sts"'";

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
}
```